# Bootstrap vertical tabs not auto changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two seperate tab boxes that change when clicked or over a 5 second periode.

[image]
[image]

The box on the left is working perfectly. However, the box on the right is changing the active but not the content.

Here is the html:
Box on the left:

```
<div class="media">
                        <div class="parrent pull-left">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                                <li class=""><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="analistic-01">Architect</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="analistic-03">AIA</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical">IRS </a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical">AKIN GUMP</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical">PWC</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical">EPA</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="parrent media-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="http://www.architectmagazine.com/awards/r-d-awards/award-green-zip-tape_o"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Awards/R&D.png"></a>
                                            <a href="http://www.architectmagazine.com/awards/r-d-awards/award-green-zip-tape_o">Click for Award</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>Architect Magazine</h2>
                                            <p>It’s hard to get simpler in conception and execution than Green-Zip Tape. The product is a substitute for the joint-compound tape that has been used between gypsum board panels since the introduction of prefabricated plasterboard in the early 1930s. The product impressed all three jurors.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="http://info.aia.org/aiarchitect/thisweek07/1005/1005n_epa.htm"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Awards/AIA.png"></a>
                                            <a href="http://info.aia.org/aiarchitect/thisweek07/1005/1005n_epa.htm">Click for Award</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>AIA Awards</h2>
                                            <p>This patented demountable tape provides an alternative method for hanging sheetrock for future de-construction and reuse. 
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-wd/1404001.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Awards/IRS.png" style="margin-top:-30px;"></a>
                                            <a href="https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-wd/1404001.pdf" style="margin-left: 20px;">Click for PLR</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>IRS PLR</h2>
                                            <p>Taxpayer's Zip type partitions installed within the Owned Property and Leased Property are included in asset class 57.0 of Rev. Proc. 87-56 for purposes of § 168.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="https://www.akingump.com/en/news-insights/david-burton-examines-irs-private-letter-ruling-on-drywall.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Awards/AkinGump.png"></a>
                                            <a href="https://www.akingump.com/en/news-insights/david-burton-examines-irs-private-letter-ruling-on-drywall.html">Click for Article</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>Akin Gump Article</h2>
                                            <p style="font-size: 12px;">The article analyzes an IRS ruling that says that zip system drywall is eligible for more favorable depreciation than conventional system drywall, despite the fact that each serves the same purpose and has a comparable cost. Burton also looks at the opportunities this creates for real estate developers and the implications for certain nontraditional real estate investment trusts.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="http://www.pwc.com/us/en/tax-accounting-services/newsletters/accounting-methods/new-rulings-provide-guidance-tax-accounting-method-issues.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Awards/PWC.png"></a>
                                            <a href="http://www.pwc.com/us/en/tax-accounting-services/newsletters/accounting-methods/new-rulings-provide-guidance-tax-accounting-method-issues.html">Click for Article</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>PWC Article</h2>
                                            <p style="font-size: 12px;">IRS rules on the depreciation classification of certain interior, non-load bearing partitions
                                            The IRS, in PLR 201404001, ruled that zip-type partitions installed within owned and leased property must be included in asset class 57.0 of Rev. Proc. 87-56 under Section 168, and that conventional drywall partitions are classified as non-residential real property under Section 168(e)(2)(B). 

                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="http://www3.epa.gov/region9/waste/solid/construction/lifecyclebuilding/#win"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Awards/US.png" style="margin-top: -30px;"></a>
                                            <a href="http://www3.epa.gov/region9/waste/solid/construction/lifecyclebuilding/#win">Click for Award</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>EPA Awards</h2>
                                            <p>Winner: Green-Zip-TapeTM Demountable Tape Drywall tape attachment system to support easy deconstruction and reuse
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/.tab-content-->
                        </div>
                        <!--/.media-body-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/.media-->
```

Box on the right:

```
<div class="media">
                        <div class="parrent pull-left">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-two">
                                <li class=""><a href="#set1" data-toggle="tab" class="analistic-01">Marek</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#set2" data-toggle="tab" class="analistic-02">Ozarks Bank</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#set3" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical">CBRE </a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#set4" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical">Habitat</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#set5" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical">Huffman</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#set6" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical">Holiday</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="parrent media-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="set1">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="Ref/Marek.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Referals/MarekBrothers.jpg"></a>
                                            <a href="Ref/Marek.pdf">Click for Referance</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>Marek</h2>
                                            <p>We recently built our new 50,000 SF headquarters building and used the Green-Zip Partition System everywhere.  To me, it’s a simple solution and one that everyone should take advantage of!
                                            <br>
                                            -<b>R. Stan Marek</b> / Chairman
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="set2">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                            <a href="Ref/Ozarks.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Referals/BankOfTheOzarks.jpg" style="margin-top: 30px;"></a>
                                            <a href="Ref/Ozarks.pdf">Click for Referance</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>Bank Of The Ozarks</h2>
                                            <p>….we now have a built in mechanism for remodeling that should be less expensive, less time consuming, and most importantly, environmentally friendly. <br>
                                            -<b>Mark D. Ross</b> / Vice-Chairman & COO
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="set3">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="Ref/CBRE.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Referals/CBRE.jpg"></a>
                                            <a href="Ref/CBRE.pdf">Click for Referance</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>CBRE</h2>
                                            <p>….there is no reason not to consider Green Zip Tape as shorter-life property for any tax payer especially based on the design intent, which was originally based on the reusable concept.
                                            <br>
                                            -<b>Matt Rader</b> / National Managing Director
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="set4">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="Ref/Habitat.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Referals/Habitat.jpg"></a>
                                            <a href="Ref/Habitat.pdf">Click for Referance</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>Habitat for Humanity</h2>
                                            <p>I am very excited about the opportunity to help others have affordable and decent housing, while also keeping more products that can be reused from piling up in a local landfill.  Now that is a winning combination!
                                            <br>
                                            -<b>Ron Collins</b> / Vice President of ReStores
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="set5">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="Ref/Huffman.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Referals/Huffman.jpg"></a>
                                            <a href="Ref/Huffman.pdf">Click for Referance</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>Huffman Drywall</h2>
                                            <p>In addition to the sustainable benefits, the financial benefits associated with accelerated depreciation are valuable to me as an owner, and could potentially add to the building’s value in the event of a sale.
                                            <br>
                                            -<b>Brandon Huffman</b> / President
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="set6">
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="pull-left boxImg">
                                            <a href="Ref/Holiday.pdf"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Referals/Holiday.jpg"></a>
                                            <a href="Ref/Holiday.pdf">Click for Referance</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <h2>Holiday Inn</h2>
                                            <p>We found that the system will be acceptable for use in Holiday Inn, Holiday Inn Express hotels, and Staybridge Suites hotels. Congratulations.
                                            <br>
                                            -<b>Scott Bruce</b>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/.tab-content-->
                        </div>
                        <!--/.media-body-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/.media-->
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var cycle = {
  onReady: function() {
    $(".nav-stacked li:first").addClass("active in");
    $("#tab1").addClass("active in");

    setInterval(function() {
      var $navStacked = $("li.active");
      var tabContent = $("li.active a").attr("href");
      if ($navStacked.is(".nav-stacked li:last-child")) {
        $navStacked.removeClass("active in");
        $(".nav-stacked li:first").addClass("active in");
        $("div " + tabContent).removeClass("active in");
        $("div#tab1").addClass("active in");
      } else {
        $navStacked.removeClass("active in").next().addClass("active in");
        $("div " + tabContent).removeClass("active in").next().addClass("active in");
      }
    }, 5000);
  }
};
$(document).ready(cycle.onReady);

var cycle2 = {
  onReady: function() {
    $(".nav-two li:first").addClass("active in");
    $("#set1").addClass("active in");

    setInterval2(function() {
      var $navStacked2 = $("li.active");
      var tabContent2 = $("li.active a").attr("href");
      if ($navStacked2.is(".nav-two li:last-child")) {
        $navStacked2.removeClass("active in");
        $(".nav-two li:first").addClass("active in");
        $("div " + tabContent2).removeClass("active in");
        $("div#set1").addClass("active in");
      } else {
        $navStacked2.removeClass("active in").next().addClass("active in");
        $("div " + tabContent2).removeClass("active in").next().addClass("active in");
      }
    }, 5000);
  }
};
$(document).ready(cycle2.onReady);
```

cycle is controlling the left box, cycle2 is supposed to control the right.
Thanks for your help!

Here is the jsfiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16660/)

Comment: make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16660/

Comment: the target does not match

Comment: what do you mean? i fixed the navStacked2 within the IF statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your function target

One change to HTML change class Name Box on the right: `tab-wrap2`

```
var cycle = {
            onReady: function () {
                $(".tab-wrap .nav-stacked li:first").addClass("active in");
                $(".tab-wrap #tab1").addClass("active in");
                setInterval(function () {
                    var $navStacked = $(".tab-wrap li.active");
                    var tabContent = $(".tab-wrap li.active a").attr("href");
                    if ($navStacked.is(".tab-wrap .nav-stacked li:last-child")) {
                        $navStacked.removeClass("active in");
                        $(".tab-wrap .nav-stacked li:first").addClass("active in");
                        $(".tab-wrap div " + tabContent).removeClass("active in");
                        $(".tab-wrap div#tab1").addClass("active in");
                    } else {
                        $navStacked.removeClass("active in").next().addClass("active in");
                        $(".tab-wrap div " + tabContent).removeClass("active in").next().addClass("active in");

                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        };
        $(document).ready(cycle.onReady);

        var cycle2 = {
            onReady: function () {
                $(".tab-wrap2 .nav-two li:first").addClass("active in");
                $(".tab-wrap2 #set1").addClass("active in");

                setInterval(function () {
                    var $navStacked2 = $(".tab-wrap2 .nav-two li.active");
                    var tabContent2 = $(".tab-wrap2 li.active a").attr("href");
                    if ($navStacked2.is(".tab-wrap2 .nav-two li:last-child")) {
                        $navStacked2.removeClass("active in");
                        $(".nav-two li:first").addClass("active in");
                        $(".tab-wrap2 div" + tabContent2).removeClass("active in");
                        $(".tab-wrap2 div#set1").addClass("active in");
                    } else {
                        $navStacked2.removeClass("active in").next().addClass("active in");
                        $(".tab-wrap2 div" + tabContent2).removeClass("active in").next().addClass("active in");

                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        };
        $(document).ready(cycle2.onReady);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16664/

Answer (score 0):

You just missed a small detail. Change this line

```
$("div#tab1").addClass("active in");
```

to

```
$("div#set1").addClass("active in");
```

This will solve your problem [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m8yt3san/). This is the line responsible for showing the tab.

Comment: The problem here is i want both tabs the change. that line is already changed on the second set of javascript but it still wont change the content

Comment: The box on the left is changing perfectly, however just the tabs are changing on the box on the right, but not the content